# Rofi on kde+i3 doesn't start with shortcut

Tags: i3-window-manager, kde-plasma-5

I use Antergos kde edition with i3wm. I'd like to run rofi. If I execute `rofi -show-icons -show run` on terminal it runs ok. But shortcut in i3config `bindsym $mod+space exec rofi -show run` doesn't launch it.